# Optimise play framework instance for 64mb server

Tags: optimization, playframework

I trying to have the best optimisation in my play
framework server.

I try to optimize with :

```
%prod.jvm.memory=-server -Xms64m -Xmx128m -Xoptimize

# Jobs executor
# ~~~~~~
# Size of the Jobs pool
play.jobs.pool=2

# Execution pool
# ~~~~~
# Default to 1 thread in DEV mode or (nb processors + 1) threads in
PROD mode.
# Try to keep a low as possible. 1 thread will serialize all requests
(very useful for debugging purpose)
play.pool=5
```

However I did not success to have good perf on 256 mb server. it seems
that http://www.playframework.org/ run on 64mb server and it work
fine. How it is possible ? Have I missed something in optimization?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 256 mb server ? If 256 mb is all the ram of your server, it is not enough.

When you do -Xmx64M you set a maximum limit for your heap size but java also needs memory for native, classloading, threads.

You also need memory for your os.

From my experience, 256 Mb is the lower limit for one java process.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons external to Play that impact performance:

- Server too busy (too many processes competing for CPU)
- Not enough RAM and server doing Swapping (performance killer)
- Slow connection that adds extra delay

You may also have issues in your application:
  - Your application is getting too many requests and it requires more RAM to manage the clients
  - You are creating too many objects in memory while processing requests, taking most of the RAM (and triggering many GC)
  - Connection to database is slow and delays responses

To be honest, there are many reasons why your app may eb slow, many related to your implementation or the server. You'll need to monitor and see what's the issue by yourself (or give us much more data on server performance, ram, swap, i/o, your code, etc)